# Line Break - dont work in Simbyone newsletter

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the Simbyone Newsletter Builder but line break is not working. can anyone help me?

```
    //edit text
    if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='text'){

    $("#sim-edit-text .text").val(big_parent.text());
    $("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
    $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

    $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
      $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500);
       big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());
     });
    }
```

Comment: Please show us you full code, this is has nothing to do with line break.

Answer (score 0):

newsletter_builder.js

```js
$(function() {
// Resize
function resize(){
        $('.resize-height').height(window.innerHeight - 50);
        $('.resize-width').width(window.innerWidth - 250);
        //if(window.innerWidth<=1150){$('.resize-width').css('overflow','auto');}

        }
$( window ).resize(function() {resize();});
resize();




//Add Sections
$("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-add").hover(
  function() {
    $("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-dropdown").fadeIn(200);
  }, function() {
    $("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-dropdown").fadeOut(200);
  }
);

$("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-dropdown").hover(
  function() {
    $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content").fadeIn(200);
  }, function() {
    $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content").fadeOut(200);
  }
);


$("#add-header").hover(function() {
    $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='header']").show()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='content']").hide()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='footer']").hide()
  });

$("#add-content").hover(function() {
    $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='header']").hide()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='content']").show()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='footer']").hide()
  });

$("#add-footer").hover(function() {
    $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='header']").hide()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='content']").hide()
        $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab[data-type='footer']").show()
  });



 $(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab-add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Insert</div>');
        $('.newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab-add').click(function() {

        $("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-content").prepend($("#newsletter-preloaded-rows .sim-row[data-id='"+$(this).parent().attr("data-id")+"']").clone());
        hover_edit();
        perform_delete();
        $("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-dropdown").fadeOut(200);
                })
  }, function() {
    $(this).children(".newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-buttons-content-tab-add").remove();
  }
);


//Edit
function hover_edit(){


$(".sim-row-edit").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).append('<div class="sim-row-edit-hover"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="line-height:30px;"></i></div>');
        $(".sim-row-edit-hover").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})
        $(".sim-row-edit-hover i").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        big_parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        //edit image
        if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='image'){


        $("#sim-edit-image .image").val(big_parent.children('img').attr("src"));
        $("#sim-edit-image").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-image .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#sim-edit-image .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
          $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)

          big_parent.children('img').attr("src",$("#sim-edit-image .image").val());

           });

        }

        //edit link
        if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='link'){

        $("#sim-edit-link .title").val(big_parent.text());
        $("#sim-edit-link .url").val(big_parent.attr("href"));
        $("#sim-edit-link").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-link .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#sim-edit-link .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
          $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)

            big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-link .title").val());
                big_parent.attr("href",$("#sim-edit-link .url").val());

                });

        }

        //edit title

        if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='title'){

        $("#sim-edit-title .title").val(big_parent.text());
        $("#sim-edit-title").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-title .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#sim-edit-title .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
          $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)

            big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-title .title").val());

                });

        }

        //edit text
        if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='text'){

        $("#sim-edit-text .text").val(big_parent.text());
        $("#sim-edit-text").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#sim-edit-text .sim-edit-box-buttons-save").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
          $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)

            big_parent.text($("#sim-edit-text .text").val());



                });

        }

        //edit icon
        if(big_parent.attr("data-type")=='icon'){


        $("#sim-edit-icon").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-icon .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#sim-edit-icon i").click(function() {
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().slideUp(500)

            big_parent.children('i').attr('class',$(this).attr('class'));

                });

        }//

        });
  }, function() {
    $(this).children(".sim-row-edit-hover").remove();
  }
);
}
hover_edit();


//close edit
$(".sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(500)
   $(this).parent().parent().slideUp(500)
});



//Drag & Drop
$("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-content").sortable({
  revert: true
});


$(".sim-row").draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-content",
      //helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid",
          handle: ".sim-row-move"
});



//Delete
function add_delete(){
        $(".sim-row").append('<div class="sim-row-delete"><i class="fa fa-times" ></i></div>');

        }
add_delete();


function perform_delete(){
$(".sim-row-delete").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
}
perform_delete();





//Export
$("#newsletter-builder-sidebar-buttons-bbutton").click(function(){

        $("#sim-edit-export").fadeIn(500);
        $("#sim-edit-export .sim-edit-box").slideDown(500);

        $("#newsletter-preloaded-export").html($("#newsletter-builder-area-center-frame-content").html());

        preload_export_html = $("#newsletter-preloaded-export").html();
        $.ajax({
        }).done(function(data) {



        $("#sim-edit-export .text").val(preload_export_html);



        });



        $("#newsletter-preloaded-export").html(' ');

        });




});
```

```html
<div class="sim-edit" id="sim-edit-text">
<div class="sim-edit-box" style="height:390px;">
<div class="sim-edit-box-title">Edit Text</div>

<div class="sim-edit-box-content">
<div class="sim-edit-box-content-text">Text</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-content-field"><textarea class="sim-edit-box-content-field-textarea text"></textarea></div>
</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons">
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons-save">Save</div>
<div class="sim-edit-box-buttons-cancel">Cancel</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```